# Webform - Show the preview page on confirmation instead

Tags: 7, webforms

I have a [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) and there are options that you can set a "preview" page if you want to. I think it's very nice displayed but I want to show this instead on the confirmation page so when a user submits the form it will get posted but the form will be displayed on the confirmation page as it did on the preview page. like a confirmation, this is your Webform that was sent it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve that like follows

Go to your Webform form settings, then find *Redirect Location* and select *Custom URL*:

Here you can insert tokens but for that you need to install the [Token](https://www.drupal.org/project/token) module.

After install and enable the Token module, Click on Browse available tokens link.

Let's say your webform URL path is node/5.

You need to insert Custom URL path like follows

```
node/5/submission/[submission:sid]
```

Then whenever user submits the webform, will be redirected to their webform submission results page.

Hope this simple solution helps you.

[image]

There is another way you can achieve that by writing some custom code in tpl files. Follow the [Print submitted data on confirmation page](https://www.drupal.org/node/1515548)