# Continue to show the preview page after submission, adding the confirmation message

Tags: 8, webforms

The preview page showing submitted values (rather than the empty form) is the ideal thing to show the confirmation message (and to adapt to better summarize what was submitted, as we have [already done for the preview page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/300890/show-a-summary-calculated-from-webform-submitted-values-on-the-submission-previe)).

Unfortunately, "Inline (reloads the current page and replaces the webform with the confirmation message)" and "Message (reloads the current page/form and displays the confirmation message at the top of the page)" both seem to reload to show the empty form, not the preview page.

Is there a way to change this, and show the preview page?

This is similar to the question [show the preview page on confirmation instead](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/135209/webform-show-the-preview-page-on-confirmation-instead), but this is for Drupal 8.  And if redirecting to submission results were recommended, i'd expect that as a pre-set option?

Comment: Have you tried the accepted D7 answer out already? It looks a bit to me that this still should work, doesn't it?

Comment: Trying that now… first thing i'm running into is that the example is a webform associated with a node, so it has a non-admin submissions path.  How do i get that for my webform, which already has a submission form alias but that doesn't translate to the submission results?

Comment: Jacob Rockowitz suggested: You could add the [webform-submission:values] token to the confirmation page’s message.